# A function that creates functions that can be interrogated for the number of times they have been called

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to create a function that creates other functions that remember how many times they have been called -- not hard. But I want to interrogate those functions at some arbitrary time in the future, not immediately after being called. It might work like this:

```clj
(defn mk-cntr []
  (let [count (atom 0)
        res (fn cntr [] (swap! count inc))]
    res))

(let [f (mk-cntr)]
  (f)
  (f)
  ; other complicated stuff here
  (f)
  ; Interrogate it now.
  (println (:count f))) ; or something similar
```

This does create functions that count how many times they have been called, but I don't want that information right after the call.

I would like to reproduce something like this JavaScript snippet:

```js
function counter() {
  function result() { result.count++ }
  result.count = 0
  return result
}
```

With this, you can do `let cntr = counter()` then sometime later interrogate it like `cntr.count` to find out how many times it was called.

I've fumbled around with function metadata but couldn't come up with something that worked. It feels like `defrecord` and `defprotocol` could be used, but that seems like a lot of bother to come up with something that is so simple in JavaScript.

Is there a simple way to implement this is Clojure/Script?

Comment: It's certainly possible, in a number of different ways, but it's not a very Clojurey thing to do. Functions should be pure, not carry around secret mutable state with them. Why do you need this? There is generally some other design that accomplishes the same goal but works better.

Comment: @amalloy: It's part of a test fixture. Comparing how many times certain paths are followed based on some inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed function with a known number of arguments you want to track you can create a record and implement `IFn` for the required arity:

```
(defrecord FC [counter]
  IFn
  (invoke [this]
    (let [res (swap! counter inc)]
      res)))

(defn mk-cntr []
  (->FC (atom 0)))
```

If you need to wrap some arbitrary function(s) I would create a record containing the wrapping function and the counter:

```
(defn mk-cntr2 [f]
  (let [counter (atom 0)]
    {:counter counter
     :fn (fn [& args]
           (swap! counter inc)
           (apply f args))}))
```

which you can then call and query:

```
(def f (mk-cntr2 println))
((:fn f) "first")
((:fn f) "second")
@((:counter f)) ;; 2
```

Comment: Implementing `IFn` is probably the way to go. But for the second example, couldn't the object returned by `mk-cntr2` itself implement `IFn`, so that you can call `(f "first")` instead of `((:fn f) "first")`?

Comment: Thank you. I had not looked into `IFn` before.

Answer (score 3):

[Metadata](https://clojure.org/reference/metadata) comes-in quite handy here.

```clj
(defn counted [f]
  (let [c (atom 0)]
    (with-meta #(do (swap! c inc) (apply f %&))
               {:count c})))
```

`counted` wraps a function, returning another one that maintains call count in it's metadata. In the style of your example:

```clj
(let [add (counted +)]
  (println "add called" @(:count (meta add)) "times")
  (println "add works as usual: 1+2 =" (add 1 2))
  (println "add called" @(:count (meta add)) "times")
  (println "sum of first 10 natural numbers is" (reduce add (range 11)))
  #_more-complicated-stuff
  (println "add called" @(:count (meta add)) "times"))

;; Prints the following

add called 0 times
add works as usual: 1+2 = 3
add called 1 times
sum of first 10 natural numbers is 55
add called 11 times
nil
user=>
```

[`add-watch`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch) is also something can you do to subscribe to this counter, so-to-speak.

Exceptions are also something to consider. What must happen when the wrapped fn throws?

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with having a bit of Java in your codebase, you could write a class that extends the [AFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java) class and wraps an [IFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java). In your Java source code directory of your project (for example, you can have a line `:java-source-paths ["javasrc"]` in my Leiningen) and there I have a file `CountedFn.java` with this contents:

```
import clojure.lang.AFn;
import clojure.lang.IFn;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CountedFn extends AFn {
    private IFn _inner;
    private AtomicInteger _counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public CountedFn(IFn inner) {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    private void step() {
        _counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _counter.get();
    }

    public Object invoke(Object arg1) {
        step();
        return _inner.invoke(arg1);
    }

    // Implement 'invoke' for all other arities too... a bit of work.
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
(import 'CountedFn)

(defn add119 [x]
  (+ x 119))

(def f (CountedFn. add119))

(f 10000)
;; => 10119

(.getCount f)
;; => 1

(f 1000)
;; => 1119


(.getCount f)
;; => 2
```